# python filter rewrite filter

Tags: python, list, lambda

Working code

```
def not_double_cap_word(word):
    cap_count = 0
    for ch in word: 
        if str.isupper(ch):
            cap_count += 1
    not_double_cap = (cap_count < 2)
    return not_double_cap    
...

    words_no_double_caps =list(filter(not_double_cap_word,words_alnum))
```

What would be a different solution, say maybe using lambdas or other patterns in Python? The above creates a new list of words with any word with more than two caps removed. one two TWo => one, two.

Comment: I don't follow your output how does `one two TWo` become  `one, two`.

Comment: What do you mean "using lambdas"? `lambda` is just a different way of writing the same kind of function that `def` gives you, one that doesn't allow you to use statements or give the function a name but does allow you to do it in the middle of an expression. Why do you think you want that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely simplify that `not_double_cap_word` function, but it's still going to be the same basic solution.

First, you can use `ch.isupper()` instead of `str.isupper(ch)`. Calling a method the normal way is always easier than calling it as an unbound method and passing the `self` explicitly.

Next, we can replace the explicit for loop with `sum` over a generator expression:

```
cap_count = sum(ch.isupper() for ch in word)
```

And we don't really need to define `not_double_cap`, `cap_count < 2` seems simple enough to return directly. So:

```
def not_double_cap_word(word):
    cap_count = sum(ch.isupper() for ch in word)
    return cap_count < 2
```

But really, this whole thing is probably simple enough to inline directly into the main expression. While you *could* do that by defining a function with `lambda`, there's no reason to. In general, `map` and `filter` are good when what you want to do to each thing is call a function that you already have lying around; comprehensions are better when what you want to do is an expression that you'd have to wrap in a function (`lambda` or otherwise) to pass to `map` or `filter`. Compare:

```
words_no_double_caps = [word for word in words_alnum 
                        if sum(ch.isupper() for ch in word) < 2]
words_no_double_caps = list(filter((lambda word: sum(map(
                           lambda ch: ch.upper(), word)) < 2), words_alnum))
```

(I think I got the parens on the second version right. If not… well, if I wanted to program in Lisp, I would.:)

Either way, it's performing pretty much the exact same steps as your original code, but it's more concise. Is it more readable? That's for you to decide. But that's the most important reason to choose one or the other, or something intermediate between the two.

Well, that, and whether or not you need to reuse this logic; if you do, it should *definitely* be defined with a `def` statement and given a nice name.

Comment: lambda word: sum(ch.isupper() for ch in word) < 2, it's simpler to just use a comprehension instead of filter. I wanted to see the lambda to see how if is complicated vs comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your `not_double_cap_word` code using `sum`:

```
def not_double_cap_word(word):
    return sum(x.isupper() for x in word) < 2
```

If you just want ti use a lambda with filter and not use the `not_double_cap_word` function:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: sum(s.isupper() for s in x) < 2 ,["one", "two" ,"TWo"])))
['one', 'two']
```